# SSL handshake error with TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I hope you can give me some ideas on this:

Recently, my local SVN repositories stopped working. I can't be certain of the cause other than updating my antivirus (ESET Smart Security), but disabling it doesn't seem to work. I have VisualSVN 2.5.5 and TortoiseSVN 1.7.7 x64 up and running, and I also have a Hamachi network set up for an app joint effort I'm making with some buddies. However, not even I can update or commit changes now because Tortoise gives me the following error:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL
'https://myserver/svn/myrepo/trunk' OPTIONS of
'https://myserver/svn/myrepo/trunk': SSL handshake failed: An existing
connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

I saw some solutions like enabling KeepAlive, or enabling logging on the Apache server to see what's going on, plus checking the Event Viewer, but I see nothing out of the ordinary. I've even tried uninstalling both VisualSVN and Tortoise and reinstalling...

BTW, I'm running Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same after upgrading to TortoiseSVN 1.7.7 in a slightly simpler setup. Going back to 1.7.6 works just fine. It's as if there was some significant SSL change between the two.

Comment: Update: In my case, the SVN server I was contacting was behind an F5 load balancer that was also doing SSL termination. Said F5 was not on the latest firmware/code, and did not have support for the new OpenSSL ciphers added in OpenSSL 1.0.1. Upgrading my F5 to a later firmware added support for those ciphers, and TortoiseSVN 1.7.7 works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Collin Allen mentioned in the comments above:

> I'm seeing the exact same after upgrading to TortoiseSVN 1.7.7 in a slightly simpler setup. Going back to 1.7.6 works just fine. It's as if there was some significant SSL change between the two.
>   -– Collin Allen Jul 9 at 17:25

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the SSL checking (under web and email / protocol filtering). It's not a full solution but at least a workaround to manage it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this was going to **ESET setup | Web access protection | Configure | Protocol Filtering | Exclude application** and I checked the TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a self-certificate as following steps:

1. Add the following registry value to the Windows registry:

   - for 32-bit system:

   `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VisualSVN\VisualSVN Server]`
   `"CreateGnuTLSCompatibleCertificate"=dword:00000001`

   - for 64-bit system:

   `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\VisualSVN\VisualSVN Server]`
   `"CreateGnuTLSCompatibleCertificate"=dword:00000001`
2. Start VisualSVN Server Manager.
3. Go to **Action | Properties | Certificate**.
4. Click **Change certificate...** and follow the wizard instructions to generate a new self-signed certificate.

Comment: the solution is for another error, it has nothing to do with the original question!